# How to activate sorting in this table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using [**DataTable**](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) plugin. The examples in the linked page are great. But I have a problem.

In the example user may sort the datatable after doing a search. I successfully do this. But when I created a filter, the sorting is messed up.

This is the expected sequence:

- Page shows all data in the datatable
- User do a filter (Show data by some filter. Like by date, by status, by country etc)
- Page show certain data with the searched filter
- User may do a search using text to view less data
- User may do sort by column

In my script, the code works until point 3. When user do a search the filtered data is reset to show all data(not-filtered)

How do I deal with this?

This is my table:

```
<table id="tbl_surat_all" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th class='text-center' width="1%">No</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="10%">ID Proyek</th>
   </tr>
   <tbody><!--Data collected from php--></tbody>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
    pageLength  : 25,
    responsive  : true,
    dom         : '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    buttons     : [
                    {extend: 'copy'},
                    {extend: 'csv', title   : "list<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>"},
                    {extend: 'excel', title : "list<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>"},
                    {extend: 'pdf', title   : "list<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>"},
                    {extend: 'print',
                        customize: function (win){
                            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                            $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('compact').css('font-size', 'inherit');
                        }
                    }
    ]
});
```

This this the filter do (It's ajax success call):

```
var row;
var no = 1;

$('#tbl_surat_all tbody tr').remove();

$.each(response, function(index, data) {

   row = "<tr><td>"+ no++ +"</td><td>"+data.idproyek+"</td></tr>";
   $('#tbl_surat_all tbody').append(row);
});
```

**Note**:
the conclusion is how do I copy the search behavior (default from the library) to my filter (my own created jquery) behavior?

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/23/

Comment: HTML tags are not proper

Comment: @JaydeepPandya what HTML?

Comment: @KissMe review <tbody>/*Data collected from php*/</tbody>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

Comment: @JaydeepPandya oh.. actually that's just a note. thx for remind me.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [search api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()), you can either search on the table as shown.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

Or you can name your columns when you initialize the datatable and search each column for text and apply that to the datatable.

```
columns: [
         {
            name: 'colName',
            data: 'colData',
            type: 'date'
         }
```

searching on the column would be

```
var col = table.columns('colname:name');
col.search('searchTerm');
table.draw();
```